# How to split panes in Windows Terminal on startup?

Tags: windows-terminal, panes

I want to start Windows terminal with multiple panes.

This does not work in `settings.json`:

```
"startupActions": "new-tab -p \"Command Prompt\"; split-pane -p \"Command Prompt\"" ,
```

and gives the following error:

> shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

while this works fine and opens multiple tabs:

```
"startupActions": "new-tab -p \"Command Prompt\"; new-tab -p \"Command Prompt\"" ,
```

How do I configure Windows Terminal to launch with multiple panes?

Comment: Which Windows Terminal version? None of these worked for me in latest one after a quick test. WT is a huge mess in general.

Comment: What exactly is the question ?

Comment: @harrymc How do I launch Windows terminal with multiple panes using configuration file ?

Comment: Would creating a function within the PowerShell profile to launch the function when the profile is read work? _(Profiles: `%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\<Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 || profile.ps1>`)_. To prevent issues with other terminals, the function could first check if `wt` is being used and execute the setting, else ignore it otherwise _(this is the default [profile](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) I start with to set the prompt colors and a few variables)_

Comment: You should answer all asked questions from the comments. Especially important one like  about version. I'll asume it's latest as I just reproduced after another quick test that now yielded the same results as yours after I worked around another bug.

Comment: @Destroy666 Version 1.18.1462.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Terminal is (still) very buggy. There are at least a few issues related to `startupActions`:

- that option doesn't work at all if the default profile is launched as admin (`"elevate": true` in `defaults` or profile that starts), see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/13929) or [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/14442) - this has been broken for at least a year
- `split-pane` didn't work in it for me (in latest Windows Terminal version) until it randomly started to, after multiple changes and restarts. I don't know what fixed it exactly, except it started working with:

```
"startupActions": "move-focus first; split-pane -p \"Command Prompt\"",
```

and now everything including your:

```
"startupActions": "new-tab -p \"Command Prompt\"; split-pane -p \"Command Prompt\"",
```

works. Perhaps some cache got cleared. There's no issue for this [yet](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20split%20pane%20startupActions%20is%3Aopen), so feel free to debug further and report one.

I honestly recommend switching to another stable terminal app, though. I'm using Windows Terminal very rarely, mostly for testing features and comparing to other terminals, and almost each time I encounter another smaller or bigger bug.

[WezTerm](https://wezfurlong.org/wezterm/index.html) is a modern cross-system one that works the best for me and has also many more features in comparison - including more robust startup capabilities in form of [workspaces](https://wezfurlong.org/wezterm/recipes/workspaces.html) which are scriptable with Lua, although it's a bit lacking on the UI side and less user-friendly.

Comment: Well, seems like my problem is a known issue and already tracked on Github so I'll just follow your recommendation and explore more stable alternatives.